# Why is "sherbet" pronounced "sherbert" so much?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

This has often stumped me.  Not being a world-traveler, I don't know how widespread this pronunciation is, but if anyone knows: where did the *r* come from?

Comment: What about "sorbet"?

Comment: You just blew my mind. I tend to be a pretty good speller but I would have sworn it was spelled "sherbert." I've always pronounced it that way -- no idea why.

Comment: "Sherbert" is a phonological alternative of "sherbet", meaning, it came from a pronounciation, but its not how it was spelt.

Comment: I guess, it's due to pronouncing "sher-bət" "sher-bət", and then American rhoticism comes into play, and it becomes "sher-bərt"etc. Note that its pronounced "sher-bit" in England.

Comment: However, it seems to be a "correct" spelling in Australasia, and pronounced (but not spelled) this way widespread throughout the US: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sherbert

Comment: Say "No thanks. I would like some SHERB'T though."

Comment: Personally, I blame Herbert.

Comment: It came from the same place as the 'r' in *warsh*. I just want to point out that Americans generally don't add 'r's after random vowels. Generally they only go after the vowels they belong after, but they've also regionally slipped into a few stray words like *wash,* *Washington,* and *sherbet*.

Comment: I'm UK, with no trace of American rhoticism. I don't think the **r** sounds out of place. An unkind soul might say this question is just a peeve.

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: *Sorbet* is frozen fruit juice *Sherbet* has milk/cream in it (somewhere between sorbet and ice-cream)

Comment: @crasic Sherbet has different meanings on different sides of the Atlantic. Over here (in the UK) sherbet is a fizzy powdery confectionary.

Comment: OP's spelling of "traveler" *really* grates on me. Luckily I took the trouble to check, and discovered that's the standard US spelling, otherwise I'd have editted the Question and started yet another war about what's 'correct'. Never mind where the **R** came from - where *did* that other **L** go to?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "*editted*"? Irony?  Happy typo?  Living up to your name?

Comment: @Malvolio: I won't lie. Crap speller.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you won't lie?  Why not?  This is the Internet, no one knows you're a dog!

Comment: @Malvolio: No no, you're getting @FumbleFingers mixed up with @Cerberus ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked at spelling in print over the last century. This NGram chart gives the an exaggerated impression of the difference. Usage figures are 160,000 for **sherbet**, and 28,500 for **sherbert**.

That's more than 1 in 6 actually *writing* the **r**, almost certainly in contravention of what they'd find if they'd looked it up in whatever dictionary they had to hand. One could reasonably assume at least that fraction would *say* it that way, if not many more.

OP implies the less common form is simply 'wrong', but I see no reason to think this. It's just an [alternative spelling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sherbert) associated with alternative pronunciation. So far as I can see, that alternative spelling has been around for several hundred years, so I guess the pronunciation has too.
[image: .]

Comment: Interesting.  According to all the etymologies I've read, it's simply a mistake.  But if it's been around for this long you'd think there would be some solid trace for the derivation.  I would suspect Northern European but I don't see anything to back it up.

Comment: @Sharon: Well it's true there's no second **r** in our translations of the 'original' forms - Turkish şerbet, Persian شربت (šarbat), Arabic شربة (shárba). But I don't see that *means* anything. It's like arguing about whether Peking / Beijing should be pronounced with a **b** or a **p**. These are foreign words that may get different approximate translations and pronunciations.

Comment: @Case 'According to all the etymologies I've read, it's simply a mistake.' gets very close to the etymological fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons:

1. They first heard it that way. This is actually the more popular pronunciation in the US, even though it is incorrect.
2. Sher-bet is harder to say because it requires a longer pause between the first and second syllable to bite off the "bet".

Comment: My grandma pronounced it sherbert. Then I said I wanted some "sherbert" and my entire family laughed at me...But at least they bought me some after they made me cry! :)

Comment: I heard, and thus said, "sherbert" when growing up.  Eventually I saw the word written and realized something odd was going on.  It's right up there with "i-urn" (iron) in my midwestern upbringing.

Comment: My family always pronounced it "sherbit"; I sometimes heard the extra-r pronunciation at school.  But my ex-mother-in-law pronounced it "sherbert" (and "wash" as "worsh", and "sandwich" as "sangrich"...) and after a while I found it infecting my own pronunciation.   Eewwww.

Comment: I'm not convinced it means much to suggest any particular form is 'harder to say'. The one you grow up with is invariably 'easier to say', I think. Even those [few, in my experience] people who pronounce **Wednesday** as it's spelt probably think that's 'easier', though I find it extremely difficult to do this even by way of speaking it as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Another very similar example is the pronunciation **perservere** for the standard **persevere**.

This is a famous example of

> **epenthesis**

with a smattering of

> **assimilation**

The phenomena (not yet an explanation of *why*) is the addition of a sound (the [epenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) ), and the sound added is by [assimilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)) (specifically progressive assimilation meaning the first sound affects the second).

As to why, well, it doesn't always happen, and in fact the opposite often happens (dissimilation, e.g. *apeture* for *aperture*, *govenor* for *governor* (note that this is for pronunciation not spelling)). So predicting when it will happen is not so clear. But we know, by the existence of other examples, that the phenomenon is not isolated.

Comment: Here's an interesting paper that discusses the topic and gives many more  examples: [R-Dissimilation in English](http://web.csulb.edu/~nhall2/dissimilation_draft.pdf)  (Nancy Hall 2007)