# Do many Americans have trouble pronouncing "fr" in "infrastructure"?

Tags: pronunciation

Infrastructure has been much in the news lately, because of the bill that has been moving through Congress for months and finally passed last week. As such, lots of people have been interviewed about it, and I've noticed that many of them pronounce the word more like "infastructure". I think these even include many of the government officials who worked on the bill.

Am I just hearing it wrong, or do many Americans have trouble pronouncing that "r"? Is it the same reason that "February" is often pronounced as "Febuary"?

I don't think I've ever noticed the "r" elided in other uses of the "infra" prefix, such as "infrared". But maybe it's due to the different communities of speakers who discuss politics versus science.

Comment: It's because they're confusing the _infra-_ prefix (meaning 'underneath', from Latin) with the _info-_ prefix (a chopping from English _information_ that now combines freely with other chopped forms, e.g, _infomercial_). All people have heard about "infrastructure" is words, after all; it's a normal confusion.

Comment: It doesn't sound like they're saying "infostructure". But I agree that "info-" is a much more common prefix because of all those portmanteaus ("infotainment").

Comment: But many of these people are Congressmembers who actually worked on the bills! It might be like the "nucular" mispronunciation, which afflicts many highly educated people.

Comment: The second vowel in both prefixes is likely to be unstressed and reduced to schwa.  And if you listened carefully to the way people actually say _infrared_, you'd find that some of them lose the first /r/ in anticipation of the second, like _February_. Oh, and you'd also find that the more often they say it, the more they slur it. That's how _God be with you_ became _good-bye_. It has nothing to do with education; most Anglophones know nothing about the phonetics of their language.

Comment: Good point. So the people who actually work on it are *more* likely to slur it.

Comment: I don't know if it's uniquely American, but it is very common here, from politicians and others. Like two frequent slurs in the political arena: *So'Security* and *Pres'nUnited States*. Is it just laziness, as some argue?

Comment: @JimMack Now you have me thinking of the Star Trek episode with "E plebNista"

Comment: What I say sounds more like *infrstructure*. It's hard to tell which side of the *r* the vowel is on. But the *r* is sort of there — it's just a lazy *r*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no element of conflation between ***infra-*** and ***info-*** prefixes affecting my pronunciation of ***infrastructure***, so I don't think John Lawler's *first* point applies to me. BUT I think I do tend to slur that first /r/ out of existence, so most likely my (often incredibly lazy) speech pattern here arises because of points made in John's *second* comment. My "non-specialist explanation" is that even before I actually articulate it, I know  ***infrastructure*** is gonna be a pretty long word (4 syllables is a definite mouthful! :) I'm trying to get it over quick.

Comment: I hear **infastructure** or "inferstructure", not **infostructure**. Also, I never really hear anyone pronounce the r in February in AmE. I hear: feb-you-airy. "Febrew-airy, anyone?

Comment: I think both "in**fer**structure" and "nu**cul**ar" just boil down to the fact that consonant clusters make the mouth do *work*, and a casual or rushed user is sorely tempted to just swap some neighboring vowels and consonants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main reason for this is optional dissimilation of the sound r in words where it occurs more than once. This also may affect the first syllable of words like *berserk, surprise* and *forward.* I give more information in this post: ['Forward' pronounced more often as 'foward'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/417922/77227)

In fact, I have noticed that I do hear or use a version of *infrared* with loss of the first r.

Although this type of dissimilation can potentially affect many words, it is not a regular phenomenon, so I’m not sure to explain why it does or doesn’t occur in specific words for any particular speaker. I also don’t know how many total speakers use a dissimilated pronunciation of “infrastructure”.

I find it implausible that it’s related to the existence of words starting with *info-.*

Comment: I "vaguely" knew ***dissimilation*** before seeing it here, but I'm afraid I tended to conflate it with ***dissimulation*** anyway. I'm older and wiser now, ty. But when I googled **dissimilation specific pacific**, I didn't see any relevant results in the first page. Is that in fact an example, or is there something else going on with people who say ***pacific*** for ***specific**?* Did I perhaps get no relevant results because the less common of the two words is ***so*** much less common?

Comment: No one pronounces the r in berserk, afaik. They say; bazerk.

Comment: Yeah, the phonetic explanation is the likely one. _INfor_ and _INfra_ can both  be (and often are) pronounced _INfer_.

Comment: Happens with other combos as well. It took me a couple mugs of coffee to parse *inkle lemon* - as in inkle lemon weather - the first time I heard a new DJ say it. Increments - inkerments, intravenous - intervenous, android - anderoid, empress - emperess.

Comment: The slurring of intra- is a particular problem, since inter- is also a valid prefix, but with a different meaning. ("Intervenous" is a term from biology, and there are probably more examples). Hyper- vs. hypo- is another.